# How to get my result from Procedure

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, scripting

How can i get my out parameters from my procedure. 
My  stl_mbc_cdr table has over 100 records and i cant see my results.

```
declare 
   call_charge VARCHAR(10);
   MSG_OUT     VARCHAR(50);
BEGIN
   FOR REC IN (SELECT *FROM dulguunbaatar.stl_mbc_cdr_1062) LOOP 
   pk_test_duba.recharge_idd(REC.Called_Number,
                               rec.call_date||rec.call_time,
                                                         rec.duration,
                                                         CALL_CHARGE,
                                                         MSG_OUT);      
    END LOOP;
end;
```

Answer (score 2):

Depends on the client you're using really, but this should work in SQL*Plus, SQL Developer etc.

```
set serveroutput on;

declare 
   call_charge VARCHAR(10);
   MSG_OUT     VARCHAR(50);
BEGIN
   FOR REC IN (SELECT *FROM dulguunbaatar.stl_mbc_cdr_1062) LOOP 
   pk_test_duba.recharge_idd(REC.Called_Number,
                               rec.call_date||rec.call_time,
                                                         rec.duration,
                                                         CALL_CHARGE,
                                                         MSG_OUT);  
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('charge: '||CALL_CHARGE||' message: '||MSG_OUT);    
    END LOOP;
end;
```

Comment: thank you for answering my question.

Comment: How can i create tempo table and insert my result to it ?